# Set the content-type with wp_remote_post

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I set the `content-type` field to `application/json` in the header of my HTTP request when using the function `wp_remote_post` ?

Answer (score 8):

Check the documentation for [`wp_remote_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) which will give you some extra information on what you can do with the remote request.

When you make the request using that function, you can set headers in the second parameter (`$args`) within an array. For example:

```php
$args = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'content-type' => 'application/json'
    ),
);

$request = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );
```